# Adding FileAppender programmatically Log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Temporarily adding a FileAppender to 'wiretap' logging in Log4j was a breeze. You could just instantiate a FileAppender, get the Logger for the class you're interested in and it worked.

Now Log4j is deprecated in favor of log4j2, but there seems to be no working API at all.

- There is no way to get a logger for the class you're interested in anymore.
- There is no way to add a FileAppender without loading and saving the whole (temporary) configuration.

I tried the Writer and the Outputstream of this examples to add an appender, but the file remains empty:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent.

What could be wrong with this, Am I missing some undocumented functionality? Is programmatically changing anything in logging configuration a big red flag and should one never attempt it?

Comment: Try http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Programmatically_Modifying_the_Current_Configuration_after_Initialization

Comment: the create fileappender method in that example is deprecated by now and it won't compile because of wrong arguments (log4j2 2.7)

Comment: @Cloud Did you try creating the file yourself and then adding the appender ? Using apache commons FileUtils.touch(new File(appenderFile)); and then doing the rest to add a file appender ?